# Discord.js Filter the command out of a sentence with prefix (like Hey Bot give me a cake)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, args

I am relatively new to JS and using discordjs. Currently, commands with prefix (+) and slash commands (/) work for me. However, only commands that look like this work: `Hey Bot ping`, `Hey Bot help` etc.

I would like the bot to filter out the command. So for example `Hey Bot show ping`. (`Hey Bot` is prefix, `ping` the command) .. I want the bot to work like Siri, like `Hey Bot show me the ping`.  But this only works with `Hey Bot ping` or `Hey Bot ping word1 word2 etc`. Maybe you have an idea how I can realize this .. Many thanks!!

**This is my command ping.js:**

```
const { Message, Client } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    aliases: ['p'],
    permissions : ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) =>
    {
        message.channel.send({ content: `${client.ws.ping} ws ping` });
    },
};
```

I tried

```
run: async (client, message, args) =>    {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("ping")) {
      message.channel.send({ content: `${client.ws.ping} ws ping` })
    },
```

instead of `` message.channel.send({ content: `${client.ws.ping} ws ping` }); `` but it don't works for me ..

**This is my how the message is create:**

*works with commands & event handler*

```
const client = require("..");
var config = require("../settings/config.json");
var ee = require("../settings/embed.json");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    let prefix = config.prefix
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.partial) await message.channel.fetch();
    if (message.partial) await message.fetch();
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) {
            message.channel.send({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(ee.embed_color)
                    .setAuthor(`TEST`)
                    .setDescription(`Use \`${prefix}help\``)
                    .setFooter(ee.embed_footertext, ee.embed_footericon)
                ]
            });
    }

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd.toLowerCase()) ||  client.commands.find((cmds) => cmds.aliases && cmds.aliases.includes(cmd));
    if (command) {
        if (!message.member.permissions.has(command.permissions || [])) {
            return message.reply({
                embeds: [
                    new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor(ee.embed_color)
                        .setDescription(`** wrong ${command.permissions} **`)
                ]
            })
        }
        command.run(client, message, args, prefix)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not ideal, Siri is very advanced, but to search for the command you can do this:

```js
const command = client.commands.find(c => message.content.includes(c.name.toLowerCase())
```

And of course you can include aliases:

```js
String.prototype.includesAny = function (args) {
  for (const arg of args) {
    if (this.includes(arg)) return true;
  }
}
const command = client.commands.find(c => message.content.includes(c.name.toLowerCase()) || message.content.includesAny(c.aliases)
```

Comment: Hey MrMythical! Thanks for your idea and code. It works so far, but now it responds to the command without the prefix `Hey Bot`. So I can use `ping` without using `Hey Bot`. That would not be so good .. I'm not sure how to use the prefix as a required factor now ..

Comment: At the top, put this: `if(!message.content.startsWith("Hey Bot")) return;`

Comment: Right, I could have thought of that myself! Thanks, dude! But I'm always getting `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` if I am adding this line .. Sorry for asking :/

Comment: You forgot 1 `)` after the `startsWith`. Also, if this helped you can mark it as correct

Comment: Works! Thanks, mate! Will mark it as correct! Another question. Can I change `Hey Bot` with something like `${config.prefix}` so I can just change the config prefix? :)

Comment: Yes, you will have to that on your own though, good luck